# Does ABAP CALL statement set SY-SUBRC value?

Tags: system, abap, function-call

I'm looking at the description of *CALL - System Function Call* in the SAP ABAP Keyword Definition. Such calls have the format `CALL 'xxx' ID 'yyy' FIELD 'zzz'.` The ABAP Keyword Definition does not mention that `sy-subrc` is set by calling a system function. But somehow, I suspect that it is.

- Can I "trust" the Keyword Definition in such a case? (`sy-subrc` not mentioned => not set)
- What would be a "good" example system function call to test it on an SAP system? (does not break/change anything, exists on all systems)

Note that I'm not an ABAP programmer and I usually handle third-party ABAP programs in Java as text / parse tree.  I know that one usually should not call system functions, but the ABAP code I look at might have such calls. Furthermore, I'm not interested in the actual value a specific system call sets `sy-subrc` to, just in the fact whether system calls set/alter `sy-subrc` or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you are asking this question you are already aware this is NOT recommended approach to use direct SYSTEM calls. However, if you still want to use them...
By using `CALL` statement SAP kernel C-modules are called and without knowing the source we can not interpret the returning value confidently, either it's 0 or 1.
Despite there are examples (see line 230 of `DYNP_VALUES_READ` FM) where `sy-subrc` value is checked after system calls, nobody except SAP knows which value to check in certain case. Nor we. 
Also there were reports ([1](http://marc.info/?l=mysap-linux-general&m=109154017827694), [2](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3319987)) about ambiguous meaning of these values during tests.

So the answer is **NO**, `sy-subrc` in this context brings no meaningful information.

P.S. Answering your questions:

1. No, you cannot interpret it that way. If something is not mentioned in ABAP Documentation then this **not known** for sure or not meaningful at all.
2. I cannot confirm this is good idea at all (to test system calls), but if you want you can try call `SYSTEM` function.

It calls arbitrary Unix command.
 For example, you can move files stored on your ABAP Server like this:

```
    CALL 'SYSTEM' 
     ID 'COMMAND' 
     FIELD 'mv /usr/sap/temporary
               /usr/sap/definite'.
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess, that answers my question. Again, I do not write code that performs such calls: I'm looking at third-party code that does so. Furthermore, I'm usually not interested in the actual value that is being set (as I do not execute the call) but if a value is set at all. For me, it makes a difference whether the sy-subrc value set by the preceding statement is still valid after the system call or not. From your answer, I deduce that system calls indeed set sy-subrc (although to a unknown value, in some cases). That's enough information for me.

Comment: I assume sy-sybrc value would be invalidated by the system call.

Answer (score 1):

Now this should be a safe call that works on any system:

```
DATA: dbserver TYPE char255.

CALL 'C_SAPGPARAM' ID 'NAME'  FIELD 'SAPDBHOST'
                   ID 'VALUE' FIELD  dbserver.
```

As you probably already know there are some [exceptions](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABAPCALL-.htm) that can occur. As for `sy-subrc`, when a command sets `sy-subrc` it is usually explicitly mentioned in the documentation including which values it can hold and their meaning. But don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 0):

Simple (harmless) function modules are `RH_GET_DATE_DAYNAME` that requires the language and 10 character date (eg. `26.10.2016`) as input fields and `DATE_TO_DAY` that only requires the 10 character date as input. The `sy-subrc` should be returned as `0` if a valid date is entered.

Comment: But 'RH_GET_DATE_DAYNAME' is a function module, not a system function. I was asking about calls like CALL 'xxx' ID 'yyy' FIELD 'ZZZ'.